# Gmail Account Login security check

Tags: gmail

My gmail  login in desktop always leads me to my android phone for security check. Its annoying. How to avoid this frequent checkup?

Comment: Are you need to avoid two-step-verification?

Comment: yes.avoid two step verification

Answer (score 0):

**Turning off 2-Step Verification**

1. In “Signing in & security” section of My Account, select 2-Step Verification. Sign in with your username, password, and verification code if asked.
2. Select Turn off 2-Step Verification.
3. A pop-up window will appear to confirm that you want to turn off 2-Step Verification. Select Ok.

**Turning off for specific devices**

You can able to add or remove your specific devices for two-step-verification. You can get more details here - https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2544838?hl=en